# How to get VsCode process id after starting it from C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, process

i have this C# code (WPF app, but it probably doesnt matter):

```cs
void StartEditing(string projectPath) {
  InitializeProject(projectPath);

  Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"path\to\Code.exe", projectPath));
  if (!process.HasExited) {
    process.Exited += (sender, args) => { CleanupProject(projectPath); }
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
  }
}
```

Basically i wanna to do some initialization before vscode starts and then do some cleanup after it exits (start/stop synchronization of changes with remote storage using FileSystemWatcher).

My code works only when there is no `Code.exe` process already running at time of call `Process.Start` method.

When there is already another `Code.exe` process (from different project), then my process exits immediately but vscode window is still opened afterwards (guessing vscode detects previous instance and pass its arguments to it before exiting)

So my question is: **How to detect, that vscode opened at `projectPath` was closed?**

PS: on my machine opening folder in vscode spawns 13 `Code.exe` processes and opening second one spawns additional 3.

Comment: I think you can pass command line args to code.exe to control whether it attaches to an existing window or creates a new one, this maybe what you need to make your code work without having to close other instances. Checkout https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options
Sorry if that doesn't help, but thought it would be worth a mention

Comment: vscode is creating new window (old window still has its old project open) but that new window is not created by process, that i started but with different one ....